# Datepart Function with If condition

Tags: sql-server

I wrote this query to insert data to **Att_process** Table **checkin_time** field.

If the **CHECKINOUT** Table **CHECKTIME** Field Hours Value < 12,  it should insert in to **CHECKINOUT** Table **checkin_time** Field. 
And if it is greater than 12 it should insert in to **CHECKINOUT** Table **checkout_time** Field

But it doesn't work, can you help me to figure this out and also i don't know how to put this on a trigger, if you can help me, I will really appreciate it.

```
IF (DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) < 12) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Att_process(USERID,checkin_time)
    SELECT CHECKINOUT.USERID,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
    from CHECKINOUT 
    where DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) < 12; 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Att_process(USERID,checkout_time)
    SELECT CHECKINOUT.USERID,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
    from CHECKINOUT 
    where DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) >= 12;
END
```

Comment: If the other value in the table is null, you can just do this without an IF statement: e.g. `INSERT Att_process (USERID, checkin_time, checkout_time) SELECT USERID, CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) < 12 THEN CHECKTIME END, CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) >= 12 THEN CHECKTIME END FROM CHECKINOUT` but this would create separate records for one userid checking in and out. If there's only two entries per userid (checkin and checkout) you can do MAX(CASE...

Comment: Also, presumably the reason it doesn't work is because in your IF statement, you're not selecting CHECKTIME from anywhere... Unless that's just an example and it's not working for another reason.

Comment: Where you get this parameter value ? => CHECKTIME

Comment: Hi ZLk,it's working,Thank you very much for the help,I have same Data base in My sql also How Can i Do the same thing on My Sql

Answer (score 1):

Plz try this

```
INSERT INTO Att_process(USERID,checkin_time,checkout_time)
SELECT USERID, 
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) < 12 THEN CHECKTIME END),
    (CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) >= 12 THEN CHECKTIME END)
FROM CHECKINOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use this trigger just change the script accordingly

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
FOR INSERT
AS
     DECLARE @uid INT;
     DECLARE @checkin DATETIME;
     SELECT @uid = i.USERID
     FROM [CHECKINOUT] i;
     SELECT @checkin = i.CHECKTIME
     FROM [CHECKINOUT] i;
     IF(DATEPART(HOUR, @checkin) < 12)
         BEGIN
             INSERT INTO Att_process
                                    (USERID, checkin_time
                                    )
             VALUES
                    (@uid, @checkin
                    );
         END;
     ELSE
         BEGIN
             INSERT INTO Att_process
                                    (USERID, checkout_time
                                    )
             VALUES
                    (@uid, @checkin
                    );
         END;
```

Comment: Hi Sanu  Antony,It's working,Thanks,How can I do the Same thing in My SQL,Because I Have Same Database In MYSQL Also

Comment: Hi Sanu Antony,this trigger Not insert data in to Att_process Table